# Tuleap Card Fields Error

Tags: php, tuleap

I have created a task and set the start date (08.04.2014) and end date(08.04.2014) as same date, hence in the card fields(included start date and end date fields) it shows as 8 hrs ago, instead of showing 8 hrs more as the day ends at midnight 12. But when I set both the dates with some days gap between them, it works fine by showing 1 day ago and as 1 day more.

Please provide a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug. I suggest you report it in the request tracker